# Help me to find Bezout's number for two polynomial .

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-algorithm

$f(x)=2x^4+5x^3+6$ 
$g(x)=x^3+2x^2+5x+4$ 
I can find $gsd(f(x),g(x))=1$ in $Z_7[X]$ but can't solve right  $gsd(f(x),g(x))=f(x)*u+g(x)*v$
because i can't get 1 when try solve left part of equation, i have 
$f(x)=(2x+1)*g(x)+(2x^2+x+2)$
$g(x)=(4x+6)(2x^2+x+2)+(5x+6)$
$2x^2+x+2=(6x)(5x+6)+2$
$5x+6=(6x+3)*2+0$
so my GCD is 2 but how i understand it must be monic polynomial. then i find:
$2=(2x^2+x+2)-(6x)(5x+6)=(2x^2+x+2)-(6x)(g(x)-(4x+6)(2x^2+x+2))=f(x)-(2x+1)*g(x)-(6x)(g(x)-(4x+6)(f(x)-(2x+1)*g(x)))$
then i open brackets 
$2=(4x)f(x)+(6x^2+4x)g(x) $
$2*1=2(2x)f(x)+2(3x^2+2x)g(x)$
but it's not equal,yes?
can you understand it for me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Somewhere in the "I open brackets" section it went wrong, cause I get $2= (3,1,1) f - (6,5,2,1)g$. Note that you can multiply both sides by $4$ to get $1= (5,4,4) f - (3,6,1,4)g$.

Comment: I was confused as I was recalculating and I had different answers several times, thank you